# how to install Ubuntu using ttySx / Uart Console?

Tags: boot, grub2

Is it possible to install Ubuntu desktop using Uart console?
Post grub changes able to see info in Uart ttyS4/5 (in my system) using Runlevel 3.
But the moment installation start to select key etc the log only coming to GPUx console not in Uart console.
Post analysis observed the default setting in ISO getty is to tty1 only not to ttySx. Therefore, is it possible to load Ubuntu using UART Console (ttySx) ? or is possible to link serial console as default in iso file to load using UART ?

Comment: https://github.com/ynkjm/ubuntu-serial-install

Comment: hi, the question is not about to divert it to console post loading it. Here i want to load/install it using Uart and there is no GFx card connected. while diverting it Uart using Grub then upto certain level data is coming in Uart console and then it stops becoz the default get tty is diverted to tty1 not ttyS(x). Is it possible to load Ubuntu (18.x) using Uart console only? Note: there is no Gfx card connected to divert data to tty(x).